# add space after nth commas in Excel, Notepad++, or emEditor?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, notepad++, macros, csv

Notepad++ 6.8.8 
I want to be able to turn several lines that start like this:

```
0,2,3,45,67,89,01,234,567,890,123,4567,8901
0,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,151,162,173,184
x,z,q,r,n,f,t,a,e,f,z,n,a
```

into

```
0, 2,3, 45,67, 89,01, 234,567, 890,123, 4567,8901
0, 7,8, 9,0, 11,12, 13,14, 151,162, 173,184
x, z,q, r,n, f,t, a,e, f,z, n,a
```

A space after the initial `0,` comma, (first number with comma afterwards) and then every 2 commas, put one blank space after the comma.

- **Not** every line will start with `0` [zero]. Can start with any digit or period `.`  possibly words sometimes.
- I want each line to be treated independently; maintain their separate line content (one line cannot wrap into another when searching for numbers and commas).

I may have another situation where I will need to add space after comma into groups of 4 after the first comma.  example:

```
x,z,q,r,n,f,t,a,e,f,z,n,a
```

to

```
x, z,q,r,n, f,t,a,e, f,z,n,a
```

Notepad++ is the preferred way to do this (regular expressions, macro, etc), but I do have EmEditor, MS Word / Excel 2010 if this helps.  It is difficult to record a macro like this, because the amount of characters before/after each comma can be different.  Please also explain the syntax that you use in case adjustments need to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in excel if you paste your lines in column A and change workingRange to your range. Then you can just copy column A back to notepad

Open Excel `Developer tab` and choose `Visual Basic` [for applications], or press `Alt + F11`.

[image: Excel Developer tab VBA screenshot]

Copy the code below into a new module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub notepadthing()

    Dim workingRange As Range
    'Set your range here
    Set workingRange = Range("A1:A3")
    workingRange.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=workingRange, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=False

Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim rowNumber As Long
Dim columnNumber As Long
Dim myString As String


For rowNumber = 1 To workingRange.rows.count
    lastColumn = Cells(rowNumber, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    myString = Cells(rowNumber, 1) & ", "
    For columnNumber = 2 To lastColumn - 1
        myString = myString & Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber) & ","
        If columnNumber Mod 2 <> 0 Then myString = myString & " "
    Next
    Cells(rowNumber, 1) = myString & Cells(rowNumber, lastColumn)
Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Make the spreadsheet you want formatted the current spreadsheet.  Switch back to VBA window and click the `Run` button (looks like a play button on a dvd or music player)

[image: Excel VBA run module]

It's just text to columns and concatenation. I'm sure there's easier way to do it.

---

The way the spacing works is here -

```
For columnNumber = 2 To lastColumn - 1
   myString = myString & Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber) & ","
   If columnNumber Mod 2 <> 0 Then myString = myString & " "
Next
Cells(rowNumber, 1) = myString & Cells(rowNumber, lastColumn)
```

It always adds a `,` but you can decide when it adds a space . Right now column 1 sits alone. So as we go through the columns, odd columns need the space `columnnumber Mod 2 <> 0`.

To change this, you need to work through the logic: there's a space after column 1 and then I need groups of 4, so column 5, column 9, column 13. But those are difficult numbers to work with and they are just off by 1 to natural multiples of four. So if I subtract one and then check divisible by four..

```
If (columnNumber - 1) Mod 4 = 0 Then myString = myString & " "
```

Comment: 1) how do I create groups of 4 instead of 2 e.g. `x, z,q,r,n, f,t,a,e, f,z,n,a` instead of `x, z,q, r,n, f,t, a,e, f,z, n,a`  2) I need some explanation or comments so I understand what part of the code is doing the spacing, finding the comma, etc. so that I can follow along. Can you [edit] your answer to include this?   I tried to format more than 3 lines of data, and I only edited the `Range("A1:A3")`.  It turns out you need to edit the `For rowNumber = 1 To 3` also.  Can you make this easier to be adjusted so I just edit in one place how many rows of data need formatting?

Comment: Now you just need to define your workingRange once at the top.

Comment: Added a part to my answer explaining how to adjust the spacing.

Comment: Perfect.  And revised explanation is much better so I can understand it.  Honestly, I was using Excel (2010) to generate the original values `x  z  q  r  n  f  t  a  e  f  z  n  a` each in adjacent cells.  Then manually highlight and copy them into `notepad++`.  But they would be pasted tab delimited.  So then I have to find/replace the tabs with commas, and still format the  `space  `  This minimizes the need to use `notepad++`, except to store the final formatted strings.  Which I will just use another excel sheet to do anyway.  Thank you Ray.

Comment: Voted for answer.  I think the only thing left (extra credit) is a custom shortcut key to run this module.  Either assigned to a module or a specific spreadsheet where the module will be called.  Any ideas?  Also, if you liked how the question was formatted, you may vote for it.

Comment: @JonGrah create a button or record a macro with a shortcut assigned to it and move this one over to it, I think that *should* work. I don't believe there's a way to create shortcuts in VBA without Send Keys

Comment: New issue:  When a cell/row is blank, but the row is within the `Set workingRange = Range("A1:A25")` a comma `,` is still placed in the blank row.  Is there any way to detect if the row (or the first cell of the row) is blank (e.g. `isblank()` or `countblank()` and skip writing anything in that row (or write `""`)?

Comment: also, when I run module on numbers that are < 1 e.g. .5 or .63, it will add a 0 in front when placing commas.  e.g. 0.5,0.63 instead of .5 and .63.  It does not inherit the number format of the cells it was copied from.  Any ideas? This warranted a [new question](http://superuser.com/q/1069402/140631)

Comment: An alternative is to adapt this to use cstr http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cstr.php

Comment: I was wondering if you could do an edit that updates the way you detect range so that I can search the entire column (e.g. A:A), but only edit cells that contain a string in them.  **So if the cell is empty or blank, you ignore any changes that cell so it remains blank.**  What happens now is that blank cells get a comma `,` added to them.  So they are no longer blank.

Comment: If you have a question about how to do that - it would be best to try it first and then ask another question if needed