# remove leading 0 in front of decimal except when a a non-zero number precedes it

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, notepad++

I have a column, which has a comma separated values inside each cell that look like this

```
0.1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4,0.5, 0.8,1.0
1.5, 1.6,2.0, 10.6,10.9, 15.2,30.75
20, 0.25,280.2, 0.29,300.2, 423,530.76
```

Like a text string.

The goal is to remove the **leading zero** in front of the decimal, but only when there is no other digit (including another 0) in front of it
I use the search replace function vba:

```
    Option Explicit
    Public Sub Replace0dot(Optional byDummy As Byte)
        Columns("A").Replace What:"0.", _
                            Replacement:=".", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

and I end up with this:

```
.1, .2,.3, .4,.5, .8,1
1.5, 1.6,2, 1.6,1.9, 15.2,3.75
2, .25,28.2, .29,30.2, 423,53.76
```

It removes all instances of leading `0.` with `.`, so you see `10.6` becomes `1.6`.  But it should remain `10.6`  How can I get a search replace equivalent that gives me:

```
.1, .2,.3, .4,.5, .8,1
1.5, 1.6,2, 10.6,10.9, 15.2,30.75
20, .25,280.2, .29,300.2, 423,530.76
```

???  Seems like there would have to be un-concatenate and re-concatenate to achieve the goal.

Comment: Split at . Check the content before . For length or check individual digital if it's and then based on location remove

Comment: Alternatively to `Split` you can also use regular expressions to look for `([^0-9])0\.` an replace to `$1.`. You can find plenty of tutorials on the net on using regular expressions in VBA.

Comment: @Mate,   @SeanClt  `split` or `regular expressions` these may work.  Did either of you intend to write a answer? I would assume there would have to be some if/then to distinguish between  `0.` and `([^0-9])0\.`.  I'm not a programmer, although I try to be logical when writing most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple approach:

- if the string **begins** with ***0.*** then drop the zero
- if the string **contains** triplets like ***{space}0.*** then drop that zero
- if the string **contains** triplets like ***,0.*** then drop that zero

Select the cells and run this code:

```
Sub fixdata()
    Dim r As Range, t As String

    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        If Left(t, 2) = "0." Then t = Mid(t, 2)
        t = Replace(t, " 0.", " .")
        t = Replace(t, ",0.", ",.")
        r.Value = t
    Next r
End Sub
```

before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

If there are other triplets that must be changed, just add another `Replace()`

**EDIT#1:**

To avoid manual selection of the cells, we can have the macro do it.........here is an example for column **A**:

```
Sub fixdata2()
    Dim r As Range, t As String

    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        t = r.Text
        If Left(t, 2) = "0." Then t = Mid(t, 2)
        t = Replace(t, " 0.", " .")
        t = Replace(t, ",0.", ",.")
        r.Value = t
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2**

In this version we append a **;** to the end of each cell just before entering text into that cell:

```
Sub fixdata3()
    Dim r As Range, t As String, Suffix As String
    Suffix = ";"

    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        t = r.Text
        If Left(t, 2) = "0." Then t = Mid(t, 2)
        t = Replace(t, " 0.", " .")
        t = Replace(t, ",0.", ",.")
        r.Value = t & Suffix
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT3#:**

In this version the **;** is appended only if it not already present in the cell:

```
Sub fixdata4()
    Dim r As Range, t As String, Suffix As String
    Suffix = ";"

    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        t = r.Text
        If Left(t, 2) = "0." Then t = Mid(t, 2)
        t = Replace(t, " 0.", " .")
        t = Replace(t, ",0.", ",.")
        If Right(t, 1) <> Suffix Then
            r.Value = t & Suffix
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#4:**

This version will not affect empty cells:

```
Sub fixdata5()
    Dim r As Range, t As String, Suffix As String
    Suffix = ";"

    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        t = r.Text
        If t <> "" Then
            If Left(t, 2) = "0." Then t = Mid(t, 2)
            t = Replace(t, " 0.", " .")
            t = Replace(t, ",0.", ",.")
            If Right(t, 1) <> Suffix Then
                r.Value = t & Suffix
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#5:**

This fixes the bug in the previous version:

```
Sub fixdata6()
    Dim r As Range, t As String, Suffix As String
    Suffix = ";"

    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        t = r.Text
        If t <> "" Then
            If Left(t, 2) = "0." Then t = Mid(t, 2)
            t = Replace(t, " 0.", " .")
            t = Replace(t, ",0.", ",.")
            If Right(t, 1) <> Suffix Then
                t = t & Suffix
            End If
            r.Value = t
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to highlight the cells within the code vs manually highlighting?

Comment: @JonGrah  **Yes**...............I will update the code to give an example.

Comment: @JonGrah  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Upvoted.  This is a very simple approach and it appears to work every time I run it.  Here is extra credit:  How would I add a semicolon `;` to the end of each row?  e.g. **0.1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4,0.5, 0.8,1.0** becomes **.1, .2,.3, .4,.5, .8,1.0`;`** ??

Comment: @JonGrah  You need a **single ;** at the end of each cell **??**

Comment: I think so.  At the end of each string (each row) that `fixdata2()` currently parses.  Currently `0.1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4,0.5, 0.8,10.5` becomes `.1, .2,.3, .4,.5, .8,10.5`. the semicolon adjustment at the end of the string will make `0.1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4,0.5, 0.8,10.5` into `.1, .2,.3, .4,.5, .8,10.5;` with the semicolon`;` at the very end of the string for each cell adjusted.  Maybe a new sub could be used just for that as so not to break fixdata2() which is working really well.

Comment: @JonGrah  I will update the macro in the morning.

Comment: ok.  Do it the same like before, where you just append the new formula `fixdata3()` or `fixdata2withsemicolon()` and a brief notes of what the new change does.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonGrah  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: fixdata3 is almost perfect.  It technically works.  But if I rerun the macro several times, it will keep the existing semicolon and then add a new one.  so it would have multiple semicolons (the old one(s), and then the new one).  Is there a way to delete the last semicolon (if present) and then add a new semicolon?  So no matter how many times I run it, there would be a max of 1 semicolon at the end.

Comment: @JonGrah  I will make the change.

Comment: @JonGrah  See my **EDIT#3**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38994/discussion-between-jon-grah-and-garys-student).

Answer (score 0):

Use this VBA code it will test every string for leading zeros

> Sub Replace0dot()

```
   Dim str As String    
   Dim ln As Long   
   Dim i As Long    

   ln = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row   
   For i = 1 To ln
   str = Cells(i, 1).Value
   If Left(str, 1) = "0" Then
   Cells(i, 1) = Mid(str, 2)
   End If
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Does not work fully when I attempt to run module (Excel 2010). It only removed the first `0` from the first `0.` in the first cell, not the whole string and not for all the cells in column A. 2)  Can you add some comments to your answer describe what parts of your code does what?  Let's say I wanted to start with A2.  Is there anything else that needs to be adjusted.  Is `i` defining each character to count after each comma `,` the string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're [still working with lines from notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/1068604/add-space-after-nth-commas-in-excel-notepad-or-emeditor) you can use an array instead of text to columns

```
Sub notepadthingrevisit()
    Dim workingRange As Range
    Set workingRange = Range("A1:A3")
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim result As String

    Dim myStrings() As String
    For i = 1 To workingRange.Rows.Count
        myStrings = Split(Cells(i, 1), ",")
        'Adjust this for accounting for the first value and remember to trim the " " at the end
        For j = 0 To UBound(myStrings)
            If Left(Trim(myStrings(j)), 1) = 0 Then
                myStrings(j) = Right(Trim(myStrings(j)), (Len(Trim(myStrings(j))) - 1))
            End If
            If myStrings(j) = Int(myStrings(j)) Then myStrings(j) = Int(myStrings(j))
            'Check here for j mod x and insert " "
            result = result & myStrings(j) & ","
        Next
        Cells(i, 5) = result
    Next

End Sub
```

Just use the information from the previous thread to insert your spaces.

Comment: Does NOT seem to work.  I wasn't sure if it was to **replace** [`notepadthing()`](http://superuser.com/a/1068627/140631) or run **after** .  I tried both and it appears to attempt to **replace** [`notepadthing()`](http://superuser.com/a/1068627/140631). What it does is create a pyramid in column E.  I had to widen the column so that you can see it in [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6do6rropkels8me/ExcelVba_notepadthingrevisited_pyramid.png?dl=0) .

Comment: [Gary's Student `fixzero()`](http://superuser.com/a/1069499/140631), works as advertised.  So after running [`notepadthing()`](http://superuser.com/a/1068627/140631), It works beautifully. You are welcome to take another stab at it.

Comment: This was instead of the notepad thing, but if you got what you need - great.

Comment: ok.  But I am curious to know you went from a perfect solution with the [`notepadthing()`](http://superuser.com/a/1068627/140631) and this solution creates the pyramid result.  Did you see [the screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6do6rropkels8me/ExcelVba_notepadthingrevisited_pyramid.png?dl=0)?

Comment: No I didn't see the pyramid